# uiscrollview in custom uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

i have built custom `UITableViewCell` "customCell",
inside it there is just `UIScrollView` "scrollView" and scrollView: has 2 subviews

in customCell class 
i put code like this to set the contentSize of scrollView

```
(void)layoutSubviews{
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480, 120);
}
```

the code get called and the contentSize work correctly, **BUT**
there is something that rechange the contentSize of self.scrollView to default value i think this because of constraints

i tried to change the contentSize in these methods but none of them solved the problem

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
-(void)buildCell // this method get called from tableView method - tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

where i should set the contentSize of my scrollView???

--
***update:***

it's strange behavior:
when i scroll the table view down, method `layoutSubviews` will get called again but this time contentSize will keep it's new value and will not get overridden or changed

--
***update 2:***

when i removed autoLayout from storyBoard file everything worked ok...... :s
\how to solve the problem without removing autoLayout

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that self.scrollView is pointing to the scrollview you think it's pointing to, and isn't nil or something else?

Comment: yes i checked it out, self.scrollView is pointing to the right view in storyBoard, and it's not nil

Comment: If it's definitely not nil at runtime you could put a KVO observer on the contentSize property to find out where it's being changed. That's a sucky way to have to debug something but it might answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***the best solution:***

- in storyBoard i removed all the subViews of scrollView
- in `-(void)awakeFromNib` i created all the views and added them programmatically to scrollView

and now every thing is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard my guess is go and use the

```
initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
```

this method gets called after viewDidLoad and it might have something to do with this.

It's pretty strange and i would comment normally to keep the discussion but the 50 reputation won't let me

Comment: it didn't work :(

but when i removed autoLayout from storyBoard file everything worked ok

Comment: i spent the whole night working on in it, because i don't want to turn autolayout off..... at last i found a good sloution

Comment: that's good to hear, mark your answer as the one so people know that the question is answered... cheers!